# Summation of series and Taylor series are giving different results

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

$A = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$ 
$B = 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \cdots$ 
$A + B = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$ 
$2A = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$ 
$2A = A + B$
$A - B = 0$
$0 = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$

Using Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+x)$
$\ln(2) = 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: You are manipulating divergent series, hence the confusion. Take a look on [Riemann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: Look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuIIjLr6vUA) for a detailed explanation on why this can't be done.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EtHF5ND3_s) Mathologer video is also suitable for this question!

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that $A$ and $B$ are not finite numbers. Essentially, they are both $\infty$ so $A-B$ is meaningless and cancellation cannot be performed as you have done.

Comment: Look at the partial sums $A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2n}$ and $B_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n-1}$.   While $A_N+B_N =\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac1n$, we have $A_N-B_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n \ne 0$.  In fact, we have $\lim_{N\to\infty}(A_N-B_N)=\log(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did wrong was to assume that you can deal with divergent series as if they were convergent. If you say that

$$
A=\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots
$$

then $A$ is a *name* of the series, but it is *not* a number (since the series diverges).

Therefore
$$
1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots
$$
is just *another* (divergent) series and it is an unfortunate option to call it $2A$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2n-1}$ diverge and manipulating divergent series is not legitimate.

---

Another way to analyze this is to look at the partial sums $A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2n}$ and $B_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n-1}$.

While $A_N+B_N =\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac1n$, we have $A_N-B_N=-\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n \ne 0$ (In fact, we have $\lim_{N\to\infty}(A_N-B_N)=\log(1/2)$).